# Solve $a_n=1+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

As first sight this appears almost trivial. But I am having serious trouble finding a solution.

Consider the relation

$$a_n=1+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i$$

for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, with $a_0=0$. Can you find an expression for $a_n$ as a function of $n$?

---

The sequence goes like $0,1,3/2,11/6,25/12,137/60,...$

I have tried to find solutions of the form $a_n=pn^2+qn+r$ without success. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I believe this series is equivalent: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number
I don't know how to prove it, however.

It does list this form (I changed it a bit to match your notation)

$ a_n = \int_0^1 \frac{1-t^n}{1-t} dt $

Comment: That's great, thank you iammax! A straightforward proof by induction says that you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we have

$$(n+1)a_{n+1}-na_n=a_n+1$$
or

$$a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac {1}{n+1}$$

thus
for $n\ge 1$,

$$a_n=a_0+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac {1}{k} $$

Answer (score 2):

Let us attempt to prove by induction that $a_n=H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n 1/k$ is the $n$th harmonic number. $n=0$ clearly works. Suppose now that $a_i=H_i$ for $i<n$. We would then have
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=1}^i \frac{1}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=k}^{n-1} 1 = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{n-k}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{n-k}{k} = nH_{n-1} - (n-1), $$
so
$$ a_{n} = 1 + \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i = 1 + H_{n-1} - 1 + \frac{1}{n} = H_n, $$
as required.